Why Brave download speed is faster then in Firefox (both without any extentions)?
Why Brave download speed is faster then in Firefox, both without any extensions and on the same computer (LAN) with Ubuntu? I tried many times. I also tried on another computer with Windows (Firefox) and a download speed was about 600 Mb/s. I prefer Firefox since the scrolling in Brave is too slow for me.




